# Walking Through Flagged Cells Individually

Tags: vba, excel

I have a stretch goal for my project that goes way beyond my current ability, but I was hoping someone here could put me on the right track. I have the following code:

```
Public ErrorCount As Integer

Sub GeneralFormat()
    ErrorCount = 0
    VLookup
    MacroFillAreas
    color
    NonZeroCompare
    MustBe
    MsgBox ("Number of Errors" & CStr(ErrorCount))
End Sub
```

I also have the following section of the code:

```
Sub NonZeroCompare()
Dim i As Long
For i = 5 To 1000 Step 1
    If Range("AK" & i).Value = "On" Then
        If Range("AL" & i).Value = 0 And Range("AM" & i).Value = 0 Then
            Range("AL" & i, "AM" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
        End If
    ElseIf Range("BC" & i).Value = 0 And Range("BD" & i).Value = 0 Then
        Range("BC" & i, "BD" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
    ElseIf Range("EJ" & i).Value = "On" Then
        If Range("EK" & i).Value = 0 And Range("EL" & i).Value = 0 Then
            Range("EK" & i, "EL" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
        End If
    ElseIf Range("ES" & i).Value = 0 And Range("ET" & i).Value = 0 Then
        Range("ES" & i, "ET" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
    ElseIf Range("FG" & i).Value = 0 And Range("FH" & i).Value = 0 Then
        Range("FG" & i, "FH" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        ErrorCount = ErrorCount + 1
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

My desired effect is to have the user be able to jump to each cell that contributes to "ErrorCount". There are thousands of cells in my workbook to manage, so being able to jump to the error on review would be great. It would be even better if it could be done with one key on the keyboard, but a button would work too.

Any ideas on how to execute something like this? Also, difficulty level? Any resources on where to begin on this type of feature? Last question: Any native features to excel that I can code in to use that won't require hardcore coding?

Comment: I would suggest writing out a spec and spending money on getting a VBA expert to do the update for you, its possible but there is a lot going on and could be complex. I short you need a new sheet that holds links to each error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach that could work in your to handle your requirements.

First, instead of holding only a count of the number of errors, we can hold a `Dictionary` object that holds references to the cell locations. Using this object, we can then inspect it for a total count of errors, locations, etc.

I'm going to show one (relatively simple) implementation below. (If you're unfamiliar with `Dictionary` objects, do some research. Basically, it holds a unique key and a corresponding value). In my case, I chose to store the address of an error cell as the key, and I just stored a blank string as the value.

First, I wrote a function to return the dictionary object holding the errors. In the simple implementation, I had a fixed range, and I stored in the address of any cell that had text 'Abc'.

Next, I wrote a helper function that returns a count of the number of objects (this is simple enough that you don't really need a helper function, but it might simplify things if making multiple calls or if you will add more customized logic).

Finally, two subroutines accomplish the final req: traversing through the errors. The first routine 'TraverseErrors`goes through the dictionary and "visits" each of the addresses. This then yields to a`DoEvents`call which allows the user to do what they need to. The`JumpAhead` routine tells the system that the user is all finished.

It is helpful to attach a keyboard shortcut to the `JumpAhead` method. To do so, while in the Excel workbook, press ALT + F8 to open up the macro window. Select the `JumpAhead` routine, then click the `Options` button in the dialog box. This allows you to enter a letter that when pressed along with the CTRL key, runs the macro. (I selected the letter e, so CTRL + e allows me to jump ahead once I've made the changes).

There are some challenges to consider. For example, my cell addresses do NOT have a reference sheet. Therefore, if this macro switches worksheets, you may run into some trouble.

Let me know of any questions.

```
Dim oDictCellsWithErrors As Object
Dim bContinue As Boolean

Private Function GetErrorsDict() As Object
    Dim rData As Range
    Dim rIterator As Range

    'This helper function returns the dictionary object containing the errors
    'If it's already been populated
    'If not, it creates then returns the object

    If Not oDictCellsWithErrors Is Nothing Then
        Set GetErrorsDict = oDictCellsWithErrors
        Exit Function
    End If

    'Some logic to create a dictionary of errors
    'In my case, I'm adding all cells that have the text "Abc"
    'Your logic should differ

    Set rData = Sheet1.Range("A2:A15")
    Set oDictCellsWithErrors = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For Each rIterator In rData
        If rIterator.Value = "Abc" Then
            If Not oDictCellsWithErrors.exists(rIterator.Address) Then
                oDictCellsWithErrors(rIterator.Address) = ""
            End If
        End If
    Next rIterator

    Set GetErrorsDict = oDictCellsWithErrors
End Function

Private Function CountErrors() As Integer
    'This function returns the number of errors in the document
    CountErrors = GetErrorsDict().Count
End Function

Sub TraverseErrors()
    Dim oDict As Object
    Dim sKey As Variant

    Set oDict = GetErrorsDict()

    For Each sKey In oDict.keys
        bContinue = False
        Sheet1.Range(sKey).Activate

        Do Until bContinue
            DoEvents
        Loop
    Next sKey

    MsgBox "No more errors"
End Sub

Sub JumpAhead()
    bContinue = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! This is incredibly complex! At least to my eyes. Let me understand it some more and get back to you. I'll try to implement it and let you know how it goes. Thank you so much!@

Comment: @CodingNovice No problem. It looks more daunting than it actually is, so break it down into pieces and I think it will make pretty good sense. It may help if you spend some time studying how `Dictionary` objects work.

Comment: So i looked into this and I'm certain this is the right way to do it. I believe that using dictionary objects will make this code extremely robust. I decided to splt the project into two sections. First to simply copy out the hyperlinks to another sheet for a quick solution, and then improve by using dictionary items once my education catches up.